# Is there a way I can make VS2010 expand or contract try blocks inside my methods?

Tags: c#

My code has a lot of try, catch, finally blocks. Unlike methods when I am in VS2010 I can't expand or contract these areas to hide the contents while developing except by adding regions.

```
        try {
            vm.R...
            vm.Qu..
            vm.T...
            vm.D...
            vm.Fil..
            vm.Type..
            vm.St..
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log(e);
            return Content(ExceptionExtensions.GetFormattedErrorMessage(e));
        }
```

Is there a technique that programmers use to tidy up code within try blocks or do I just have to live with these larger blocks of code.

Comment: Sorry, didnt see you did not want to use regions.

Comment: My preferred method is to remove the try/catch blocks. They are almost always a mistake.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Can you explain a bit more about why they are almost always a mistake. Thanks

Comment: See [tag:exception-handling], especially http://stackoverflow.com/tags/exception-handling/info.

Comment: @Gemma - try/catch is really expensive. In most cases you can check if a certain operation will fail or not before you execute them (e.g. by checking for null values).

Comment: It's also not necessary, and usually not useful, to catch exceptions in every method. In most cases, most exceptions should be allowed to propagate up to code that can either handle the exception, or else inform a human in an appropriate way.

Comment: @Gemma Hide Selection didn't do what you want?

Answer (score 16):

Without actually modifying the code, the only thing I know of is to use outlining.  You can "hide" a selection which basically creates an outline section that you can expand and collapse just like a class, namespace, method, #if block, etc.  To do this:

- Select the lines you want to collapse.
- Choose Edit\Outlining\Hide Selection (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> with the C# keyboard scheme)

The selection is now collapsed and you can expand it and re-collapse it any time you want just like a method.  (e.g. with +/- glyph at the left or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>)

Comment: This is amazing !!!   I really did not know this existed and it's exactly what I need. Thanks very much. From now on my code can look a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

For really clean code, try [Extracting Methods](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html), so that your blocks are smaller. And, if it's really necessary, you'll get the automatic code folding from Visual Studio.