# Hide #if Preprocessor Directives statements if Compilation Symbol is not defined

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way in Visual Studio to hide the #if statements if the Conditional Compilation symbol is not defined? It would be nice if there's an option, it will make codes like below look neat when the #if statements are not needed.

**#if Statements Shown:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUP09.jpg

**#if Statements Hidden:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PpVb.jpg

Comment: Nope, no way to do that. What you view in the editor isn't "compiled", it's just a view of the file.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.I'm thinking may be there could be an Add-on.

Comment: Do you really want to be editing code without awareness that some other code might be switched on in/around it? With your "hidden" version, if someone adds new code between (say) `DoWork2` and `DoWork3`, should it be positioned before or after the code that sets `work2FinishTime`? Having that code completely hidden sounds like a nightmare to me.

Comment: You can always hide them with the +/- signs on the side.

Comment: you can also arbitrarily collapse code in VS 2010+ with "Hide Selection" http://stackoverflow.com/a/12399463/5620  w.r.t. an add-on: yes, anything is possible with an add-on; but keep in mind you'd have to be able to parse c++ code to do that...